# How "cf push" works?

Tags: cloud-foundry, blue-green-deployment

Applying `cf push` on existing `Running` application, stops and starts the application instance with new artifact.

This application has route name assigned.

---

1) In order to assess the downtime for a banking app, amidst `cf push`, what are the steps involved from stopping existing application instance to starting new application instance?

2) Does Blue-Green deployment decrease the downtime?

Comment: This is far too broad to cover in an SO question ([this intro](https://www.cloudfoundry.org/trainings/cloud-foundry-beginners-zero-hero/) is a day's course, for example) and not really a *"practical, answerable problem"* per the [help/on-topic]. Also there's a bunch of information in the docs (please start reading those), beginning with https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/overview.html.

Comment: Why have you made it *broader*?!

Answer (score 2):

1. The steps done in a `cf push` are explained in the flowchart shown [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/how-applications-are-staged.html) This includes

   - creation of application
   - upload
   - staging
2. Blue green deployment eliminates downtimes caused by pushes of new application versions.
   The basic workflow is described pretty well in the [documentation](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html). The basic idea is to deploy the new version side by side to the old one, assigning the route of the application to both of them, the remove the route from the old version. This way, there is no unavailability for the application route. 
   There is at least the CF CLI plugin [blue-green-deploy](https://github.com/bluemixgaragelondon/cf-blue-green-deploy), which will help you automate this workflow, so you do not have to take care of the single steps.